# SQL request multiple left join and null

Tags: mysql, join, null

I have 3 tables :

```
* User : iduser , pseudo, password, email, admin
* Message : idmessage, sender, recipient, time, message
* Contact : user1, user2 (both refer to id user)
```

I'm looking for a way to get contacts for a specific iduser with the last message send or received and the message time. (Order by time if possible)

In contact table, there is only one entry for a contact, so if user1 and user2 are friend, there will be only one entry in that table (user1: iduser1, user2: iduser2).

I can get contact with :

```
SELECT iduser, pseudo, email 
FROM user WHERE iduser!=/*ID GENERATED BY PHP*/ 
AND (
iduser 
IN ( 
    SELECT user1 
    FROM contact c1 
    WHERE c1.user1=user.iduser 

    UNION 

    SELECT user2 
    FROM contact c2 
    WHERE c2.user2=user.iduser))
```

I can get Contact and message but only for contact who have at least one message in database. I would use LEFT JOIN but the problem is that iduser can match with sender OR recipient, so I can't do just one relation needed by LEFT JOIN. So, this request work just for contact who have messages, can you help me to adapt this request for getting all the contact from a user and only the last message if it exist?

That's the way I used to get contact with message only

```
SELECT iduser, pseudo, email, idmessage, message, time 
FROM user, message m1 
WHERE (sender=iduser OR recipient=iduser) 
AND iduser!=4 AND ( iduser 
IN ( SELECT user1 
     FROM contact c1 
     WHERE c1.user1=user.iduser 

     UNION 

     SELECT user2 
     FROM contact c2 
     WHERE c2.user2=user.iduser)
   ) 
   AND time=(SELECT MAX(time) 
             FROM message m2 
             WHERE (sender=user.iduser 
                    OR recipient=user.iduser))
```

The result I would have :

```
IDuser    Pseudo    Email     Message   Time
1         Jean      x1@x.com  Hi!       2014-03-04 15:00
2         Luc       x2@x.com  Hello!    2014-03-05 23:00
4         Paul      x3@x.com  Bye!      2014-03-06 15:00
6         Tom       x4@x.com  Hey!      2014-03-07 14:00
```

I explain exactly what I would have. There is a IDUser generated by PHP
I would have : Id, pseudo and email from friends of the user given. It work with my first request. But I would have more information, for all the contact of the given user, I would have the last message of the row user. If a contact havn't send or received any message I would have the user in the list too.

Comment: You can, you know, do `LEFT JOIN contact AS c ON (u.id=c.user1 OR u.id=c.user2)`  Does that help? If not, please give a clearer example of the result set you want.

Comment: I tried to do with this solution but it doesn't work, maybe I don't find the right way to use that. I edited my post to explain more. Thank you

Comment: I see no column `iduser` in your table definitions. What is `iduser`?

Comment: i corrected that, id and iduser were the same

Comment: I think it's too hard to do, I'll make that with 3 requests, thank you for answers

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the messages between contacts with something like this:

```
select *
from users u join
     contacts c
     on c.user1 = u.id or c.user2 = u.id left join
     messages m
     on m.sender = c.user1 and m.recipient = c.user2 or
        m.sender = c.user2 and m.recipient = c.user1
where u.id = @YOURID;
```

To get the most recent requires a bit more trickery.  I think this does what you want:

```
select u.iduser, c.*, m.*
from user u join
     contact c
     on c.user1 = u.iduser or c.user2 = u.iduser left join
     message m
     on m.sender = c.user1 and m.recipient = c.user2 or
        m.sender = c.user2 and m.recipient = c.user1
where not exists (select 1
                  from message m2
                  where (m2.sender = m.sender and m2.recipient = m.recipient or
                         m2.recipient = m.sender and m2.sender = m.recipient
                        ) and
                        m2.time > m.time
                 );
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6b5fb/10) is a SQL Fiddle for this query.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, i tried this way but it still have 2 problems :
*If a contact haven't any message, the contact won't be in the resultset<br/>
*There are multiple entry for one user
I would have only one entry by contact with the last message.
(I probably not explain exactly what I would have, sorry for confusion)

Comment: @X4V18 . . . The `not exists` should handle those cases.  Can you set up a SQL Fiddle?

Comment: of course, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6b5fb/2
You helped me a lot i'm not far from the right request. With your first request I have too much message, so i try to group by iduser having max(time), it work but i haven't null entry.

Comment: @X4V18 . . . You have a `having` clause with `time = NULL`.  That will generally fail.  Perhaps you mean `max(time) is null)`?  However, I don't know why you have the `having` clause in the first place.

Comment: the only problem is that the group by ... having max(time) remove entry where time=null and i want to get the last message or if there isn't any message null value.

Comment: @X4V18 . . . That is not how you do it.  I have a second query for that purpose.

Comment: I woud have all friends of a specific user and the last message send or received by the row user. It seems to be more difficult than i think,

Comment: yes but the second query don't contain friends without message in message table. That's why I try to adapt it

Comment: and another problem is that there are multiple row for one user. I don't find a solution, I'm looking for that since yesterday and I think it is too hard

Comment: @X4V18 . . . As you specify in the question, there is one row for each user and each contact.

Comment: it's difficult for me to explain the best I can, I don't speak very good english and I try to do the best I can... Sorry and big thanks for the time you take for me.
For the request I just want one row per user and for each user the last message or null if there isn't any message with this user. Is it possible you know?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT iduser, pseudo, email, idmessage, message, time FROM user, message m1 WHERE (sender=iduser OR recipient=iduser) AND iduser!=4 AND ( iduser IN ( SELECT user1 FROM contact c1 WHERE c1.user1=user.iduser UNION SELECT user2 FROM contact c2 WHERE c2.user2=user.iduser)) AND time=(SELECT MAX(time) FROM message m2 WHERE (sender=user.iduser OR recipient=user.iduser))
```

this is what i want but this request doesn't show the contact without message...